# How to fix a broken character in a System Font - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, characters

My System Font is broken! A character - backslash **" \ "** is displayed as W crossed with underscore in the middle of W! Look at this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HBPV.jpg) to see this character.

This is probably happening, because I changed default System Font to **"Dotum"** which is a Font from a Korean language pack according to this [tutorial](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_personal-insiderplat_pc/how-to-disable-anti-aliasing-in-windows-10/9e1370e9-9eaa-4840-97ed-0fee855e6e88?auth=1). I use Windows 10 Pro, display language: **English Philippines**. I don't know what is default Windows Font FYI. And before I changed Font to **Dotum** - I didn't have this issue.

**Goal:**
is any way to fix the broken character.

I had an idea to edit the **"Dotum"** Font and replace this W character crossed with underscore with a normal backslash from another System Font. But I don't know how to do this! I don't know even how to locate the font on the harddisk, as it doesn't show in C:\Windows\FONTS, but in Font Settings when I press Windows+I was precisely listed this location... And I enabled show hidden files and unchecked 4 respective boxes!

**PS:** I did an extensive google search, but I wasn't able to find anything relevant to the problem! I need this Font, so changing the Font is not a solution!

Comment: This is normal. You get a yen sign for a path separator in Japanese and a won in Korean.

Comment: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html

Comment: @user1292580 , this is an excellent answer.  Why post it as a comment?  I would take a little more from your referenced website, show the important stuff and use the website as your reference.  GET DEM POINTS!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. You get a yen sign for a path separator in Japanese and a won in Korean.

See http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html

> The character in question is U+005c, the REVERSE SOLIDUS, also known
> as the backslash or '\'. It is the path separator for Windows, which
> is encoded at 0x5c across all of the ANSI code pages.
>
> Since path separators are a pretty important requirement, the title of
> this post may seem a little scary -- how could it not be a backslash,
> a reverse solidus?
>
> Well, on Japanese code page 932, 0x5c is the YEN SIGN, and on Korean
> code page 949, 0x5c is the WON SIGN.
>
> Which is not to say that 0x5c does not act as a path separator -- it
> still does. And which is also not to say that the Unicode code points
> for the Yen and the Won (U+00a5 and U+20a9) do act as path separators
> -- because they do not.

So it's because Dos did it so Windows did it too.

Comment: I know it is normal, are you kidding me right now? As I said: I want to fix that character by replacing it with a backslash from other System Font. Gotta have these points :D :D :D